# POE circuit with small transformer and small volume footprint

Tags: buck, flyback, poe, iot

I would like to make an isolated POE802.3af controller that can convert POE ~48V to 5V 2A, but the main problem is most designs use a standard POE transformer that has multiple coils. The problem with multiple coils is they are bulky and take up lots of volume.

For example the TPS27331
[image]
Source: [TPS23731 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps23731.pdf?ts=1704835144683&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fpower-over-ethernet-poe%252Fproducts.html)

If designing an IoT device this makes the design difficult if it's volume constrained. One way around this is to drop isolation and use a low end buck, but this presents a few challenges as it makes the device more susceptible to ESD, it also nullifies any way to get an 802.3 certification as Ethernet/POE needs to be isolated for this standard.  Is there a way to use a small transformer in an isolated flyback POE design?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the MP8107 uses a flyback topology that is isolated and can use a smaller 2 coil transformer. The overall footprint is ~1"x0.7"

[image]
Source: https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp8017.html#gallery-1